# MySQL - order of ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY param1, param2, param3
```

There is a table which holds the priorities of these params - **param, priority (int)**.

I would like to execute the above query in such a way that the param which has the highest priority would be in first place in the ORDER BY statement, after this the second, and the third will be last one.

Is it possible in MySQL. If yes - how?

Comment: How does the schema look? You don't order by params, you order by columns (buts that a minor detail).

Comment: Is this what you want? `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY priority DESC`

Comment: Do you mean the priorities table contains the names of the columns to be used in ORDER BY? If so, you will need to build your query dynamically. Google for something like `mysql dynamic sql` to learn more about it. Search this site specifically as well, I'm sure you'll find many examples of using dynamic SQL in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You dont order by just specific values in the column..you order it by the whole column, in your case column priority

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY priority ASC
```

Priority 1 will be first ( you can use DESC if u want Priority 1 to be the last one)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you would use `find_in_set()` or `case` (the latter is the ANSI standard):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY find_in_set(priority, param1, param2, param3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY FIELD(priority, param1, param2, param3);
```